# From producer side, how we can avoid sending duplicate messages for standard queue

Tags: amazon-sqs

I am sending messages to standard queue, some time one message is coming multiple times with different message id but same message body. how we can avoid sending this duplicate messages.

In consumer side, I am deleting the message once processing is completed.

sending message to queue :

SendMessageRequest send=new SendMessageRequest("queueUrl",message);
amzon.sendMessage(send);

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an SQS FIFO queue that allows for [message deduplicaton](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagededuplicationid-property.html) based on the message body.

Comment: Thanks for u r reply. Actually I want to use standard queue only. So how we can do any idea?

Comment: Could you clarify your situation?  Your producer writes once, but the consumer reads the same message two times?

Comment: No. Actually consumer side I am deleting the message from queue after processing. The problem is in producer side. Producer didn’t get response after sending. How we can avoid sending duplicate messages from producer side.